# Full screen applications on dual monitor setup

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, nvidia, xrandr, optimus

Optimus on Linux is far from perfect however using the native `nVidia` drivers most issues I had in the past are mainly resolved except one.

Whenever I run a full screen application, like `Kodi` or some `Steam` games the position is off, either the screen is centered right in the middle of the 2 screens on exactly 1080p or is rendered showing only the left half on any display.

I think this is due on how I made the multi monitor setup working using `xrandr`.
When `sddm` initializes it runs the following command:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --output HDMI-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --panning 3840x1080+0+0/0x0+0+0/0/0/-1920/0
```

It works perfectly however as you might notice the container is 3x1080p as this is due to having 3 screens (all being 1080p), disabling my internal display and using panning I am able to shift the output for 2 monitors right next to each other.

It appears I cannot control full screen behavior, noor in `KDE` or by using `put`. Playing around in the applications settings I can select which monitor to render it on, but it renders in the center anyways.

To clarify:

```
xs on monitor left at 1920/2
ys on monitor left at 1080
xe on monitor right at (1920/2)+1920
ye on monitor right at 1080
```

[Here is a link for visual reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcSca.jpg)

To be honest, I've tried many things and I'm at a loss here. I'm not a Linux expert, I've been using it for about 4 years as my only operating system.

Since KDE supports `Wayland` I am willing to give this a try however due to the amount of issues I had with Optimus in the past I am reluctant to try it out because everything is running so smoothly and there is little information about Optimus / Nvidia / Wayland compatibility.

Is there anything I might perhaps I've missed before doing anything as radical as changing a stable display manager for a new one? Or perhaps one simplistic command from the terminal for running applications I missed out completely.

Any help is appreciated.

### Additional information:

xorg.conf, xorg.conf.d is empty.

```
Section "Module"
    Load "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection
```

Request more information if needed in comments.

Comment: at present wayland is unusable with the nvidia proprietary drivers (but works fine with nouveau).  dunno how optimus affects this.

Comment: @quixotic Little, I need propriety to be able to get the HDMI port working on the discrete video card. Bumblebee only go's as far as enabling the port for a specific application. Meaning if its true what you're saying nouveau will not be able to support multiple monitors. But I've read `nvidia` was working on `mir` and `wayland` support, but that was a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 1):

I've used some [scripts](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/tree/10045e603a66992f1cc0c1ad01c4c09ce88b05c0/.screenlayout) on top of `xrandr` for some years now to set up side-by-side and (currently) tee-shaped desktops on Arch Linux. It should be a simple job to adapt [side-by-side.sh](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/10045e603a66992f1cc0c1ad01c4c09ce88b05c0/.screenlayout/side-by-side.sh) to your needs:

```
#!/bin/sh
eval `\`dirname -- "$0"\`/monitor_resolutions.sh`
expected_monitors=2
if [ "${monitor_count:-0}" -ne "$expected_monitors" ]
then
    echo "$0: Expected ${expected_monitors} monitors; found ${monitor_count:-0}." >&2
    exit 1
fi

xrandr \
    --output "$monitor1_name" \
        --mode ${monitor1_width}x${monitor1_height} \
        --rotate normal \
    --output "$monitor2_name" \
        --mode ${monitor2_width}x${monitor2_height} \
        --right-of "$monitor1_name" \
        --rotate normal
```

[monitor_resolutions.sh](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/10045e603a66992f1cc0c1ad01c4c09ce88b05c0/.screenlayout/monitor_resolutions.sh) helper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# NAME
#        monitor_resolutions.sh - Variables for monitor resolutions
#
# SYNOPSIS
#        eval `./monitor_resolutions.sh`
#
# DESCRIPTION
#        Prints a set of `eval`-able variable assignments with monitor name,
#        width and height for each monitor plus a monitor count.
#
# EXAMPLES
#        eval `./monitor_resolutions.sh`
#               Assign monitor1_name, monitor1_width, monitor1_height,
#               monitor2_name, etc. and monitor_count variables.
#
# BUGS
#        https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/issues
#
# COPYRIGHT
#        Copyright (C) 2013-2014 Victor Engmark
#
#        This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#        it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#        the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#        (at your option) any later version.
#
#        This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#        but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#        MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#        GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#        You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#        along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
################################################################################

monitor_info() {
    xrandr --query | tee ~/.xsession-xrandr-query
}

monitor_resolutions() {
    # Input: XRandR monitor info
    # Output: Lines with monitor name, width and height separated by spaces
    while read -r word1 word2 _
    do
        if [ "${word2:-}" = 'connected' ]
        then
            IFS='xi ' read -r width height _
            printf '%s %d %d\n' "$word1" "$width" "$height"
        fi
    done
}

monitor_assignments() {
    # Input: Lines with monitor name, width and height separated by spaces
    # Output: eval-able variable assignments for each input value, including a final count
    count=0
    while read monitor width height
    do
        count=$(($count + 1))
        printf "monitor%d_name='%s'\n" "$count" "$monitor"
        printf "monitor%d_width='%s'\n" "$count" "$width"
        printf "monitor%d_height='%s'\n" "$count" "$height"
    done
    printf "monitor_count='%s'\n" "$count"
}

monitor_info | monitor_resolutions | monitor_assignments
```

Run `side-by-side.sh` in your local [`.xprofile`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/10045e603a66992f1cc0c1ad01c4c09ce88b05c0/.xprofile#L27-L33) or otherwise just after starting X, and you should be good to go.

This setup has worked with both AMD and nVidia video cards, using both proprietary and open source drivers. I don't think I've ever tried with Wayland instead of X, but I suspect that should work iff `xrandr` works with Wayland.

Comment: I've tested, modified and tried multiple things with this code and couldn't get it working resulting in screen tearing, no screen or that the screen just didn't refresh (except my mouse) (on the second monitor connected to the nvidia chip). It really is the panning that fixes this, but at the same time likely the cause of the problem itself.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'm afraid this is the limit of my own knowledge, as the investigations stopped once I had a working setup.